# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'longitude'

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, coordinates, geopy

I am trying to get coordinates for a 'city' column of a dataframe. That city column has a dtype of ('O'). Its a list of city names. I have made sure there are no digits or numbers within the city name. This is the function i run to get coordinates:

```
def get_coordinates(city_list):
    """Takes a list of cities and returns a dictionary of the cities and their corresponding coordinates."""
    geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent='location script')
    dicto = {}


    for city in city_list:
        


        try:
            location = geolocator.geocode(city)
        except:
            raise Exception("There was a problem with the getCoordinates function")
        coordinate_values = (location.longitude, location.latitude)  #in geopandas, the x value corresponds to the longitude while the y value, the latitude(Just in case you were wondering why it was *location.longitude, location.latitude* and not the other way round )
        dicto[city] = coordinate_values #adding the coordinate pair to the dictionary at the end of every loop
    return dicto #finally retruns the dict
```

Then:

```
#getting coordinates for each city in the list
city_coords_dict = get_coordinates(city_list)
city_coords_dict
```

Final output:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-63-dedf916e4307> in <module>
      1 #getting coordinates for each city in the list
----> 2 city_coords_dict = get_coordinates(city_list)
      3 city_coords_dict

<ipython-input-62-c391f86b76db> in get_coordinates(city_list)
     13         except:
     14             raise Exception("There was a problem with the getCoordinates function")
---> 15         coordinate_values = (location.longitude, location.latitude)  #in geopandas, the x value corresponds to the longitude while the y value, the latitude(Just in case you were wondering why it was *location.longitude, location.latitude* and not the other way round )
     16         dicto[city] = coordinate_values #adding the coordinate pair to the dictionary at the end of every loop
     17     return dicto #finally retruns the dict

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'longitude'
```

Anyone with suggestions will greatly be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your error implies that `geolocator.geocode(city)` is returning `None` for one of your cities.

Answer (score 0):

Your geolocator apparently does not have data for the specific city that it is trying to request. As [not_speshal also said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69865658/attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-longitude#comment123499319_69865658), `geolocator.geocode(city)` is returning `None` at some point, which is being assigned to `location`. So later, you try to get `location.longitude`, which, because `location` is now `None`, is equivalent to `(None).longitude`...

Comment: I can understand all that, that is why im asking for a suggestion or alternative

Comment: The please add more information to your question, such as what value is failing.

Comment: I have added:  ` for city in city_list:
        
        if 'None' not in city_list:`

When i run it with this 'IF' statement, then the output actually, gives me the first city coordinate in a dictionary. However, just one, the first one. What is stopping from getting the rest?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of throwing an exception, geocode returns a NoneType object. So Nominatim is not able to find one of the locations listed in "location script".

Try replacing the try catch block with `assert location, city`

Comment: when i try doing that, the output: Exception: There was a problem with the getCoordinates function

Comment: Hi, I think the try catch block is still there. It is printing exactly the output of the catch statement. If it was unclear, what I meant was removing the lines 4 lines inclusive and after `try: ...`  with two lines: 1: `location = geolocator.geocode(city)` and 2: `assert location,city`.